# PHP parsing XML from URL

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using this code to get some XML from a URL:

```
$url = 'http://***';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

This is giving me an empty result, but the following link gives me the correct results:

```
$url = 'http://***/rss';
```

I can't seem to see the difference between these links and I don't know how to find the answer on Google. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start here http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Your first URL contains XML validation issues, it is not valid XML code. 
If you can't change that source or you cannot contact who is creating that source you will better code yourself your own PHP parser.

Comment: @Martin [what isn't valid about it?](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fshelly.ksu.ru%2Fe-ksu%2Fget_schedulle_aud%3Fp_id%3D563&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (PHP won't care about the warnings).

Comment: I've tested both and they could be parsed by simple xml. What's the problem?

Comment: hek2mgl: really? Can you share your code with us?

Answer (score 2):

This xml file charset isn't UTF8 charset, but you can see the StdObject with this :

```
    <?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $url = 'http://shelly.ksu.ru/e-ksu/get_schedulle_aud?p_id=563';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $data);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

    print_r($xml);
```

Comment: No, it's not working for me... Secondly link give xml with UTF-8 charset

Comment: The http response is: charset=WINDOWS-1251

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this work perfectly:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8");
$url = 'http://***';
$xml_string = file_get_contents($url);

$utf_xml_string = iconv("cp1251", "utf8", $xml_string);
print_r(" *** iconv() ***\n");
print_r($utf_xml_string);   
print_r("\n\n");
```

I am using iconv to convert string.